# C++: Dynamically create array named after for loop iterator

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, naming

Hey so I want to create `n` arrays (based off user input) of size `x` (also off user input). The way I was thinking of doing it was having a for loop perform `n` iterations and inside the loop ask the user for `x`. The problem is I'm not sure how to name the array using the variable `n`, I was thinking something like:

```
cout << "Enter n: ";
cin >> n

for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter x: ";
    cin >> x;

    double*array+i;
    array+i = new double[x]
}
```

To sum up my question is: can you create/name an array using a variable in C++?

Comment: Can't do this in C++.  You basically need to create an array of arrays (or, since this is c++, a `vector` of `vector`s)

Comment: *"array named after for loop iterator"* - Why would you need an array with specific name? This doesn't sound like a right thing to do. Just use `std::vector< std::vector<double> >`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. If you are using C++, then go for a `std::vector<std::vector<double>> myMatrix`, which allows you to access items in the inner arrays like so: `myMatrix[x][y]`. If you want to use fixed-size arrays, then you can go for `std::array<std::vector<double, N>, M> myMatrix`, which creates an MxN matrix. Please use http://en.cppreference.com/w/ to understand how to work with these containers.

Comment: @MihaiTodor That is a terrible way to define a Matrix! Your memory will be all over the place; please do not advise people to do it like that!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Henry! It would be useful if you gave as much information as you can in your question. For example, why are you doing this? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain It really depends on your application. Indeed, it is overkill for a double, but it solves many headaches...

Comment: @MihaiTodor No it doesn't; unless extremely large, a matrix of size MxN should be stored in an array of MxN objects, regardless of type. See `boost::ublas`. (Optimisations can be made for sparse/banded matrices.)

Comment: @AlexChamberlain So, what would be the matrix size where you expect this to actually matter? What if I need a 10 x 10 matrix of objects of type Mammoth that contain all sorts of stuff in them? I sure hope you won't suggest that I should use `boost::ublas` for that... Based on the OP's question, I doubt that he's implementing Strassen's algorithm, so please let's not get into the pitfall of optimizing code before actually writing it and let's help the poor guy get a grip on the language first.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't do this in C++. Try something like this...

```
std::cout << "Enter n: ";
std::cin >> n

std::vector<std::vector<double> > arrays(n);

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Enter x: ";
    std::cin >> x;

    arrays[i].reserve(x);
}
```

`reserve` only allocates, but does not construct the objects in the `std::vector`; if you want to construct them too, use `resize`.

PS Never use `using namespace std`; it makes your code harder to read and debug.

Comment: +1, i'd change reserve to resize. reserve only changes capacity, not size

Answer (score 0):

Here's 3 solutions: the first is closest to your example code, the second is an improvement in order to be able to correctly retrieve the array elements within bounds, and the third is the reason why you are better served with `vector`s.

**Solution 1:**

It looks like you want your arrays to have names that are distinguishable by your loop iterator. Like Joe said, you could have an array of an array, so the inner arrays will be named array[0], array[1], ..., array[n - 1]. This will be achieved by using a pointer to pointer to double. Each of the inner pointers will be used to dynamically allocate arrays of double. Don't forget to delete the dynamically allocated memory.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    std::cout << "Enter number of arrays: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    double** array = new double*[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int size;
        std::cout << "Enter size of array " << i << ": ";
        std::cin >> size;
        array[i] = new double[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {
            int element;
            std::cout << "Enter element " << j << " of array " << i << ": ";
            std::cin >> element;
            array[i][j] = element;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        delete [] array[i];
    }
    delete[] array;
    return 0;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

However, with the above code, you will have trouble accessing the elements of each inner array. Unless you memorized the size of each inner array you create with this, you might access something out of bounds. Therefore, an update to this code would be to add yet another array, let's call it `sizeOfInnerArrays`, where each of its element `i` keeps track of the size of inner array `array[i]`. Here's the update:

```
    #include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
        unsigned int n;
        std::cout << "Enter number of arrays: ";
        std::cin >> n;
        double** array = new double*[n];
        unsigned int* sizeOfInnerArrays = new unsigned int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter size of array " << i << ": ";
            std::cin >> sizeOfInnerArrays[i];
            array[i] = new double[sizeOfInnerArrays[i]];
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfInnerArrays[i]; ++j)
            {
                int element;
                std::cout << "Enter element " << j << " of array " << i << ": ";
                std::cin >> element;
                array[i][j] = element;
            }
        }

        //prints out each array as curly-brace enclosed sets of doubles
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            std::cout << "{";
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfInnerArrays[i] - 1; ++j)
            {
                std::cout << array[i][j] << ", ";
            }
            std::cout << array[i][sizeOfInnerArrays[i] - 1] << "}" << std::endl;
        }

        // free dynamically allocated memory
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            delete [] array[i];
        }
        delete[] array;
        delete[] sizeOfInnerArrays;

        return 0;
    }
```

**Solution 3:**

However, that is too complicated, so you are better off using a container, like `vector`, as Joe suggested, whose data member keeps track of its size.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    std::cout << "Enter number of vectors: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > myVec;
    // ^ space between closing angle brackets not needed
    //   if using C++11 conforming compiler

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int size;
        std::cout << "Enter size of vector " << i << ": ";
        std::cin >> size;
        std::vector<double> temp;
        temp.reserve(size);
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
        {   
            double value;
            std::cout << "Enter next value of vector " << i << ": ";
            std::cin >> value;
            temp.push_back(value);
        }
        myVec.push_back(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < myVec.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "{";
        for (int j = 0; j < myVec.at(i).size() - 1; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << myVec.at(i).at(j) << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << myVec.at(i).back() << "}" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: new[] and delete[] are sooo last century

Comment: I used regular arrays first because that's closest to OP's example code. I made an edit to add extra solutions. In the second solution, I added an array that keeps track of the other arrays' sizes in order to retrieve elements within bounds. This sets up the incentive to use vectors in the third solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are programming in C++, you should use STL containers (especially `std::vector`) instead of C-style arrays.

If you need to access an array by using the string that has been created in runtime, then you could use `std::map< std::string, std::vector<double> >`, which is pretty crazy idea though:

```
typedef std::vector<double> MyVector;
std::map<std::string, MyVector> myVectors;

// create an array:
std::string arrayName;
arrayName = std::string("someArray");       // could be: std::cin >> arrayName;
myVectors[arrayName] = MyVector(10, 1.23);  // new vector of size 10

std::cout << myVectors["someArray"][4];     // prints 1.23
```

I'm not sure what exactly is what you are trying to achieve, but there are most likely more appropriate solutions. Is it really necessary to access these arrays via their names? I'm pretty sure that common `std::vector< std::vector<double> >` would suffice here.